IFrame Content Security Policy (CSP) Bypass in Neutralino.js
I want to know how to disable Content security policy headers in neutralino.js.
I want to add the header(title bar) on the top of the app. And the website should be opened in the iframe below the title bar header.
But the website doesn't allow me to get it inside the iframe.
So I want to know how to bypass the CSP header in neutalino.js as it is an electron like javascript framework.
So I want to know how to bypass the CSP header in neutalino.js as it is an electron like javascript framework.
